# THREE.js - Dark room (without windows) while daylight outside- is it possible?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using THREE.js for my project, trying to create "real shadow effect": there is a building without any internal light. The parts that are close to the entrance shall get light from outside, but the more you going inside, it shall be dark.

In my code here http://www.crazygao.com/Easy3D/lightingtest.htm something wired is happening: Although the walls of the tunnel receiving the correct shadow, the floor receiving only slight shadow and remain "light" even I going deeply inside. There is another polygon positioned against the light, absourdly he getting very strong shadow even though there are no walls attached to it. But if I will add walls, it will get less shadow...

My question is: If it is possible in THREE.js to achieve such "dark building" effect, so the more I will go in to a building the more it will get dark, while outside the building is normal light?

Comment: There is something odd about your geometry, from the side it looks like the floor is sloping up.

Comment: Yes, the wooden floor is slopping up 30m length 2m height, but I have no idea if this affecting the light (even though it is inside the tunnel)

Comment: Is the geometry manifold? The two sides of the sloping floor should really be triangles.

Comment: Try the folllowing: 1. Give the 3 sides and top to your room "thickness" so the shadow camera will block all light on the inside. 2. Use `MeshPhongMaterial` for the interior of the room, not `MeshLambertMaterial`. 3. Add a dim `PointLight` with a `distance` parameter just inside the opening of the box.

Comment: I have tried it, but the sloping floor is still too light...

Answer (score 0):

After a small playing with the lights, I got to a solution:

1. Use double sided polygon to the floor that is light
2. Ambient outside can be 0x808080
3. Each face material have self-ambient of 0x202020 (which is enough), where there is no light it will get dimm (shadow) by default.

Example can see here: http://www.crazygao.com/Easy3D/lightingtest.htm